# Getting response from Php in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php script which forms part of a login process, I pass the data from the login page to the process.php  page via ajax, now this works, but what i am trying to do is get a response back in the form of a 1 or a 0  and then generate an action based on the result.

here is my code.

```
 (document).ready(function(){
$('form.login').submit(function () {
var user = $(this).find("[name='user']").val();
var pass = $(this).find("[name='pass']").val();
var sublogin = $(this).find("[name='sublogin']").val();

// ...
    $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://www.server.co.uk/process.php",
data: {
    user : user,
    pass : pass,
    sublogin : sublogin,
},
 success: function(response){                       
        if(response == "1")
                    {
                        text = "Logged In";
                        /*
                            login successfull
                        */
                    }
                    // Login failed
                    else
                    {
                        text = "Error";
                    }


        //alert(response);
    }
});
```

And the process.php code

```
  function procLogin(){
  global $session, $form;
  /* Login attempt */
  $retval = $session->login($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'], isset($_POST['remember']));

  /* Login successful */
  if($retval){ 
  echo '1';

  }
  /* Login failed */
  else{
    echo '0';
  }
```

}

I think my problem is the way I am trying to pass the information back from the php page to the login page.

UPDATE:  I can get a response back, using a response container in the javascript, i can echo the correct result for example 1 if the system logs in or 0 if it fails.  What i can't seem to work out is how to take the responding result 1 or 0 and have it activate the if else statement.  Sorry probably wasn't clear enough earlier.

Comment: how is procLogin called ?

Comment: Have you used a debugger like Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug to look at the response you are getting from the server?

Comment: Through another function on the page which i didn't show because that works fine, I can echo the response from the procLogin function in the login page to show the result of 1 or 0 but

Answer (score 0):

do one alert in the result of the ajax. And see if it's ok with your PHP.

But I guess that is not going is because when accessing the php script is inside a function[procLogin()] that is never called.

remove the function and let loose code

Comment: Hi, The ProcLogin function is working, as i can echo the 1 or 0, it's just the if else statement doesn't respond to the value.

Comment: You mean the else if inside `ProcLogin`, or in the JavaScript? `text =` won`t do anything. You have to affect the DOM.